# VMware View clipboard redirection / PCoIP and Virtual channels

Tags: vmware

I'm having an issue with clipboard redirection on Horizon View. Here are the GPO settings I'm using:

[image]

Copy/Paste between the virtual machine and physical workstation doesn't seem to work still however =(

I think everything else is enabled properly as well in GPO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have done the trick:
http://www.boche.net/blog/index.php/2011/11/22/enabling-vmware-view-pcoip-copypaste/

In particular this: "The required policy can be found in the pcoip.adm template. It’s called Configure clipboard redirection (note that for this to work, virtual channels must not be disabled. You can read more about View PCoIP General Session Variables here). I configured the policy for Enabled in both directions and applied the computer portion of the policy to the OU where the VDI session computer account object lives (I disabled the user portion of the GPO)."